# implementing surfaceview in xamarin forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, camera, surfaceview

I have this app I'm building that requires my camera in a surface View on my app in xamarin forms could someone point me in the right direction or tell me if there's some strong tutorial that could give me a really good insight on it.
[This is the Camera UI I need to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tetTB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> implementing surfaceview in xamarin forms

`SurfaceView` is not a Android native view, so if you want use it in `Xamarin.Forms`,     you must use [CustomRenderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

Here is an example: [Custom Renderer about SurfaceView](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/View)

> This sample demonstrates a custom renderer for a Xamarin.Forms custom control that's used to display a preview video stream from the device's camera.
>
> For more information about this sample see [Implementing a View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view#creating-the-custom-renderer-on-android).