# SurfaceView for MediaRecorder in XAMARIN FORMS C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, surfaceview, mediarecorder

Please help...

I cannot figure out how to create a SurfaceView in my Android application for use with MediaRecorder.
I have looked at many tutorials and it seems for this to be accomplished in Xamarin Forms C# I need to use a 'Custom Renderer', Ive even found examples but I still have no idea how to implement. I just want a frame/surface view to send frames too

Comment: Here is a similar issue on StackOverflow: [implementing surfaceview in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378137/implementing-surfaceview-in-xamarin-forms).

Comment: Hi that is one of the exact tutorials that I don't understand how to get the surfaceview working from and the 'custom renderer' he points to doesn't even have a surfaceview in it.

Comment: It's not easy to achieve that. Maybe this can be helpful :[Screen capture](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/main/android5.0/ScreenCapture/ScreenCapture/ScreenCaptureFragment.cs).